# Closure inside Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the charge method defined for MainCharacter class and inside it, another onload function for the image.

```
var MainCharacter = function(canvas, X, Y) {
    this.canvas = canvas;

    this.X = (typeof X === "undefined") ? 10 : X;
    this.Y = (typeof Y === "undefined") ? 10 : Y;

    this.frameX = 0;
    this.frameY = 0;
    this.frameXWidth = this.frameX + 32;
    this.frameYHeight = this.frameY + 33;

    this.img = document.createElement('img');
    this.img.src = 'assets/img/maincharacter.png';
};

MainCharacter.prototype.charge = function() {
    this.img.onload = function() {
        self.canvas.drawImage(self.img, 0, 0, 55, 55, 12, 12, 80, 80);
    };
}
```

My problem is that this closure is not taking the object, and I am doing the next to solve the problem:

```
MainCharacter.prototype.charge = function () {
    var self = this;
    var img = this.img;
    img.onload = function () {
        self.canvas.drawImage(self.img, 0, 0, 55, 55, 12, 12, 80, 80);
    };
}
```

How I can solve this properly?

Comment: You meant `this.canvas.drawImage(this.img, 0, 0, 55, 55, 12, 12, 80, 80);` in the first example?

Comment: This seems to be a proper solution (except for the unnecessary `img` variable). What are you asking for?

Comment: How is your question different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback? Please [edit] your post, if there's no difference I'll go close it as a duplicate

Comment: yes, it does not take this.canvas. It says undefined.

Comment: Is 'this' set correctly when MainCharacter.charge is called?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)?

```
MainCharacter.prototype.charge = function () {
    var img = this.img;
    img.onload = function () {
        this.canvas.drawImage(this.img, 0, 0, 55, 55, 12, 12, 80, 80);
    }.bind(this);
}
```